# How to read a link from a cell in Google Spreadsheet if it's inside href tag (gspread)

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I am new to stackoverflow, so I sorry in advance if I do something wrong

I have a spreadsheet on Google sheets, for example, [this one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v8vM7yQ-27SFemt8_3IRiZr-ZauE29edin-azKpigws/edit?usp=sharing)

And there is a link in the cell inside the href tag. I want to get the link and the text of the cell using Google Sheets API or gspread.

I have already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62780104/get-link-inside-href-tag-from-cell-in-google-spreadsheet-gspread) but I get access token 'None'.

I have tried to web scrape with beautifulsoup, but it didn't work as well.

As for bs4 solution, I tried using this code, that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152242/how-to-obtain-data-from-a-public-google-sheets-using-python)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v8vM7yQ-27SFemt8_3IRiZr-ZauE29edin-azKpigws/edit#gid=0').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
tables = soup.find_all("table")

content = []

for table in tables:
    content.append([[td.text for td in row.find_all("td")] for row in table.find_all("tr")])

print(content)
```

Comment: can you try `=REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A2),"""(.+)"",")` change `A2` to the correct cell. What did you try with beautifulsoup can you post the code ?

Comment: @manakin I edited the question and added the code

Comment: As far as I can see, Google spreadsheet is not a plain HTML table, so it likely doesn't make sense to parse it as a HTML table and try to get data between the tags <td></td>.

Comment: @YuriKhristich so what would be better to do?

Comment: I'm sure it should be done via Google Drive API. Something like this: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python or https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html or https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ But I haven't tried this yet. I can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's the full code if anyone needs it

```
import requests
import gspread
import urllib.parse
import pickle



spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
cellRange = "Yoursheetname!A1:A100"  # Please set the range with A1Notation. In this case, the hyperlink of the cell "A1" of "Sheet1" is retrieved.


with open('token_sheets_v4.pickle', 'rb') as token:
    # get this file here
    # https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in
    credentials = pickle.load(token)

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# 1. Retrieve the access token.
access_token = client.auth.token

# 2. Request to the method of spreadsheets.get in Sheets API using `requests` module.
fields = "sheets(data(rowData(values(hyperlink))))"
url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + spreadsheetId + "?ranges=" + urllib.parse.quote(cellRange) + "&fields=" + urllib.parse.quote(fields)
res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token})
print(res)

# 3. Retrieve the hyperlink.
obj = res.json()
print(obj)
link = obj["sheets"][0]['data'][0]['rowData'][0]['values'][0]['hyperlink']
print(link)
```

**UPDATE!!**

More elegant solution is this. Creating service:

```
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'secret/secret.json'
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'sheets'
API_VERSION = 'v4'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']


def Create_Service():
    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'secret/token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
    with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
        cred = pickle.load(token)

if not cred or not cred.valid:
    if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
        cred.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        cred = flow.run_local_server()

    with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(cred, token)

try:
    service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
    print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
    return service
except Exception as e:
    print('Unable to connect.')
    print(e)
    return None

service = Create_Service()
```

And extracting links from each sheet in a spreadsheet in a form of convenient dictionaries

```
    fields = "sheets(properties(title),data(startColumn,rowData(values(hyperlink))))"
    
    print(service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=self.__spreadsheet_id,
                                     fields=fields).execute())
```

So, how fields work. We go to [Spreadsheet object description](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets?hl=en#Spreadsheet) and looking for JSON representation. If we want to return, for example sheet object from that json representation, we just use this **fields = "sheets"**, because Spreadsheet has field "sheets" it its json representation.

Ok, cool. We got sheets object. How to access sheet object fields? Just click on that thing and look for its fields.

[image: where to look for object description]

So, how to combine fields? It's easy. For example, I want to return field "properties" and "data" from sheets object, I write the fields string that way: **fields = "sheets(properties,data)"**. So we just list them as arguments in an ordinary function but without space.

The same applies for objects that return data fields and ect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `def _spreadsheets_get(self, params=None)` method in `gspread/spreadsheet.py` to achieve this.

Example:

```
params = {
    "spreadsheetId" : "spreadsheet_id_here",
    "ranges" : "Sheet1!A1:A1",
    "includeGridData" : True
}
print(spreadsheet._spreadsheets_get(params=params))
```

This will return a JSON object that contains hyperlink-related data in the `textFormatRuns` section.